# Use different Azure Subscription ID per environment in a Gitlab CI pipeline

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, sh, gitlab-ci

We have a gitlab pipeline which I am trying to configure to use a different Azure subscription per environment without much luck.

Basically what I need to be able to do is set the environment variables `ARM_CLIENT_ID`, `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET`, `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`, `ARM_TENANT_ID` to different values depending on the environment being built.

In the cicd settings I have variables set for `development_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`, `test_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` etc with the idea being I assign the values from these variables to the ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID variables in the pipeline.

This is what my pipeline looks like

```
stages:
  - infrastructure-validate
  - infrastructure-deploy
  - infrastructure-destroy

variables:
    DESTROY_INFRA: "false"
    development_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $development_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    development_ARM_TENANT_ID: $development_ARM_TENANT_ID
    development_ARM_CLIENT_ID: $development_ARM_CLIENT_ID
    development_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $development_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

before_script:
  - rm -rf .terraform
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init

.terraform-validate:
    script:
        - export ARM_SUB_ID=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        - export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${!ARM_SUB_ID}
        - export ARM_CLI_ID=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_ARM_CLIENT_ID
        - export ARM_CLIENT_ID=${!ARM_CLI_ID}
        - export ARM_TEN=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_ARM_TENANT_ID
        - export ARM_TENANT_ID=${!ARM_TEN_ID}
        - export ARM_CLI_SECRET=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
        - export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=${!ARM_CLI_SECRET")
        - echo $development_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
        - echo ${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
        - terraform workspace select ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
        - terraform validate
        - terraform plan -out "terraform-plan-file"
    only:
        variables:
            - $DESTROY_INFRA != "true"

development-validate-and-plan-terraform:
    stage: infrastructure-validate
    environment: development
    extends: .terraform-validate
    only:
        refs:
            - main
            - develop
    artifacts:
        paths:
          - terraform-plan-file
```

The variable substitution works fine when I test locally but in the pipeline it fails with

```
/bin/sh: eval: $ export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${!ARM_SUB_ID}
line 139: syntax error: bad substitution
```

I think the problem is the terraform image does not have bash available, only sh but I can't for the life of me work out how I do the same substitution in sh. If anyone has any suggestions, or knows a better way of using different Azure subscriptions for different environments in the pipeline I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define different jobs for each environment that extend your main `.terraform-validate` job template, and define the environment variables on that job. This way you don't have to do the indirect substitution that seems to be giving you trouble. That would look something like this:

```yaml
.terraform-validate:
  stage: infrastructure-validate
  script:
    - echo ${ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}
    - terraform workspace select ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}
    - terraform validate
    - terraform plan -out "terraform-plan-file"
  only:
    variables:
      - $DESTROY_INFRA != "true"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform-plan-file

development-validate-and-plan-terraform:
  extends: .terraform-validate
  environment: development
  only:
    refs:
      - main
      - develop
  variables:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $development_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    ARM_TENANT_ID: $development_ARM_TENANT_ID
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: $development_ARM_CLIENT_ID
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $development_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET

production-validate-and-plan-terraform:
  extends: .terraform-validate
  environment: production
  only:
    refs:
      - main
  variables:
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $production_ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    ARM_TENANT_ID: $production_ARM_TENANT_ID
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: $production_ARM_CLIENT_ID
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $production_ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
```

Then you define all the `development_*` and `production_*` vars in the GitLab CI/CD settings.

Note that I also moved the `stage: infrastructure-validate` and `artifacts: ...` directives to the template since I'd imagine they're the same for all environments.